# How to show a marquee text in every activity

Tags: android

How to let marquee text to show in every activity. Just write at one place and the marquee text should be reflect in every activity. How to do this..please help

Comment: Place one textview at every xml's common area and then settext to that textview from string resources

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is one way to do that.
first create a BaseActivity that will be extended by every activity whose marquee is similar for every activity.

```
public abstract class BaseWaalaMarquee extends Activity {
    FrameLayout flBaseActivity;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.base_layout_marquee);
        appendView();
    }

    private void appendView() {
        flBaseActivity = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.flBaseActivity);
        View mainView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(getLayout(), null);
        flBaseActivity.addView(mainView);
    }

    public abstract int getLayout();
}
```

create a base layout for this activity named base_layout_marquee as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fact"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Loading... More text to see if it spans or not and want more">

        <requestFocus
            android:duplicateParentState="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
    </TextView>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/flBaseActivity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

now create your own layout for the activity like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f00f0f"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Your custom Layout" />
</LinearLayout>
```

finally create you activity that extends BaseWaalaMarquee as below

```
package ram.materialnavigation.opengltravis;

import ram.materialnavigation.R;

/**
 * Created by view9 on 12/16/15.
 */
public class ExtendedBaseActivity extends BaseWaalaMarquee {

    @Override
    public int getLayout() {
        return R.layout.your_custom_layout;
    }
}
```

Now invoke ExtendedBaseActivity and see the result.
I guess this will be quite helpful for you. cheers

Comment: Its looking a nice approach, but where i have to set the textView because i am setting it within onCreate of baseWalaMarqee but nothing happened.

Comment: are you talking for marquee text ? if yes then put text in base_layout_marquee. it should work. But if you want to keep any different views then put those in your_custom_layout it should work. I have compiled it and run it sucessfully working

Comment: hmmm very glad that I could help you :)

Comment: currently i am showing the marquee text in the bottom of the activities, now i also want this marquee text in the top of the activities.Sometimes i have to show it at bottom and sometime at the top of an activity, and for this i have to change my xml everytime. Is there a way to overcome this? By using flag or something else.

Answer (score 2):

Simple..Take a global string variable and change it accordingly and use it in all the activities.

Comment: But how to show this text at the bottom, do i have to use fragment for this with in acitivity..

Comment: I think your have to use Fragment instead of multile Activity.

Comment: But there are a lot of activity already running in my app. Then in those activity how to get a common  marquee text at the bottom